# A multiple choice question on span and linearly independent subset of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{v_1,v_2...v_n\}$ be the linearly independent subset of vector space V, where $n\geq 4$. Set $w_{ij}=v_i-v_j$. Let W be the span of set $\{w_{ij}:1\leq i,j\leq n \}$.

Then

1.$\{w_{ij}:1\leq i<j\leq n \}$ span W.

2.$\{w_{ij}:1\leq i<j\leq n \}$ is a linearly independent subset of W.

3.$\{w_{ij}:1\leq i\leq n-1,j=i+1\}$ spans W

4.dim W=n

Taking the set S={(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0)} $\subset \mathbb R^5$, I found 1 and 3 are true , but I  need general case .  Does there exist any simplest method to solve it? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first try to see why the first option is true.

Notice that given any $i,j$.

$$w_{ij}=v_i-v_j=-(v_j-v_i)=-w_{ji}.$$

Hence it suffices to consider the cases when $i<j$. (the case when $i=j$ is trivial)

Now to see why condition 3 holds.

Let us assume $i<j$.

\begin{align*}
w_{ij}&=v_i-v_j \\
&=v_i-v_{i+1}+v_{i+1}+\ldots-v_{j-1}+v_{j-1}+v_j \\
&= w_{i,i+1}+w_{i+1,i+2}+\ldots +w_{j-1,j}
\end{align*}

Hence condition 3 is true.

WIth condition 3, we can see that $dim(W)\leq n-1$, hence, condition 2 and condition 4 are false.

Extra homework: prove or disprove that  $dim(W)= n-1$, ;)

Comment: Sir, is it rank or dim (W) in your last line ?

Comment: it is dim. Thanks.